# Eloquent findOrFail()->get()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Bit of a rookie error I know, but can I ask...

Why does

```
findOrFail()->get();
```

or

```
findOrFail()->first();
```

Return the whole collection, opposed to just failing? The correct syntax I know is just:

```
findOrFail();
```

However an accidental ->get() on the end has caused me a nightmare!

Answer (score 5):

The `findOrFail($id)` method returns a **single model** by finding through `id` column and throws an exception - `ModelNotFoundException`, if model is not found. The `get()` method return the collection of models/rows.

If you need to find and expect only one model in return by using id, use `findOrFail()` method only. You dont have to use `get()` in the end. You can catch the exception and show the respective message in response. Also, you don't have to use `first()` method in this case, because `findOrFail()` method will return only one model result.

If you expect a collection of models, use `get()` method in the end. If there is no result, you'll get an empty collection or array and no exception will be thrown in this case, as the result will be an empty collection/array.

Answer (score 1):

Both `findOrFail` and `firstOrFail` throws an exception if the model is not found. This is the default behaviour : https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

Comment: Thanks. Yes I do understand what find or fail does. My question was more to do with adding a get() to the end of a find or fail. I understand this is not correct but of you do this the result is the collection in full.